# Getting req.body empty while using FormData API with multer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mern, multer

I am working on a project which takes image files and other data on the mongo db. While registring user i am taking a profile picture and it is uploading correctly. And once the user register by selecting role as caregiver, then i am giving them the form for applying for caregiver account in which i am taking certificates(array) images and they also are uploading without any issue. But the issue is when i try to update the profile with new profile picture and certificates then I am unable to recieve data on the backend. And it works fine with other routes but with this route I am getting req.body as empty and getting this on console :  `http://localhost:8070/undefined 404`

This is my modal for updating profile:

```
import {
  Avatar,
  Box,
  Button,
  Chip,
  Modal,
  Paper,
  TextField,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { AiOutlineCloudUpload } from "react-icons/ai";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { hideLoading, showLoading } from "../../redux/features/alertSlice";
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const UpdateProfileModal = ({ isOpen, onClose, caregiver }) => {
  const [editedData, setEditedData] = useState(null);

  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const params = useParams();

  const [profilePictureDisplay, setProfilePictureDisplay] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getNurseInfo = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.post(
          "http://localhost:8070/api/v1/caregiver/getCaregiverInfo",
          { userId: params.id },
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
            },
          }
        );
        if (res.data.success) {
          setEditedData(res.data.data);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    getNurseInfo();
  }, [params.id]);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    // Special handling for preferredCities to convert the string to an array
    if (name === "preferredCities") {
      const citiesArray = value.split(",").map((city) => city.trim());
      setEditedData((prevData) => ({
        ...prevData,
        [name]: citiesArray,
      }));
    } else if (name === "qualification") {
      const qualArray = value.split(",").map((qual) => qual.trim());
      setEditedData((prevData) => ({
        ...prevData,
        [name]: qualArray,
      }));
    } else if (name === "specialisation") {
      const specArray = value.split(",").map((spec) => spec.trim());
      setEditedData((prevData) => ({
        ...prevData,
        [name]: specArray,
      }));
    } else {
      // For other fields, directly update the state
      setEditedData((prevData) => ({
        ...prevData,
        [name]: value,
      }));
    }
  };


  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      setProfilePictureDisplay(URL.createObjectURL(file));

      setEditedData((prevData) => ({
        ...prevData,
        profilePicture: file,
      }));
    }
  };

  const handleCertificateImageChange = (e) => {
    const files = e.target.files;
    const fileList = Array.from(files);

    const imageFiles = fileList.filter((file) =>
      file.type.startsWith("image/")
    );

    setEditedData((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      certifications: [...prevData.certifications, ...imageFiles],
    }));
  };

  const removeCertificate = (certificate) => {
    setEditedData((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      certifications: prevData.certifications.filter(
        (cert) => cert !== certificate
      ),
    }));
  };

  const handleSumbit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("userId", user._id);
    formdata.append("name", editedData.name);
    formdata.append("address", editedData.address);
    formdata.append("yearsExperience", editedData.yearsExperience);
    formdata.append("feesPerDay", editedData.feesPerDay);
    formdata.append("description", editedData.description);
    formdata.append("ageRange", editedData.ageRange);
    formdata.append("availability", editedData.availability);
    formdata.append(
      "preferredCities",
      JSON.stringify(editedData.preferredCities)
    );
    formdata.append("qualification", JSON.stringify(editedData.qualification));
    formdata.append(
      "specialisation",
      JSON.stringify(editedData.specialisation)
    );

    formdata.append("profilePicture", editedData.profilePicture);
    editedData.certifications.forEach((certification, index) => {
      formdata.append(`certifications[${index}]`, certification);
    });


    try {
      dispatch(showLoading());
      const res = await axios.patch(
        "http://localhost:8070/api/v1/caregiver/updateCaregiver",
        formdata,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        }
      );
      dispatch(hideLoading());
      if (res.data.success) {
        toast.success(res.data.message, {
          position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
        });
        onClose();
      } else {
        toast.error(res.data.message, {
          position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(hideLoading());
      console.log(error);
      toast.error("Something went wrong", {
        position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="">
        <Modal
          open={isOpen}
          onClose={onClose}
          className="flex items-center justify-center pt-44  overflow-y-scroll"
        >
          <div className="">
            <form
              action=""
              method="patch"
              encType="multipart/form-data"
              className="max-w-4xl"
              onSubmit={handleSumbit}
            >
              <Box className="mt-14">
                <Paper elevation={3} className="p-6">
                  <div className="bg-white p-4">
                    {/* Profile Picture and Avatar */}
                    <div className="flex items-center space-x-4">
                      <div className="bg-white p-3 rounded shadow-md w-full">
                        <div className="mt-1 bg-[#f3f4f6] flex items-center justify-center px-6 pt-5 pb-6 border-2 border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded-md">
                          <div className="space-y-1 text-center">
                            <label
                              htmlFor="file-upload"
                              className="relative cursor-pointer rounded-md font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 focus-within:outline-none focus-within:border-indigo-300"
                            >
                              <span className="flex items-center justify-center gap-1">
                                <AiOutlineCloudUpload /> Upload a profile
                                picture
                              </span>
                              <input
                                id="file-upload"
                                name="profilePicture"
                                type="file"
                                accept="image/png,image/jpg,image/jpeg"
                                className="sr-only"
                                onChange={handleFileChange}
                              />
                            </label>
                            <p className="text-xs text-gray-500">
                              PNG, JPG, JPEG up to 10MB
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <Box>
                        <Avatar
                          alt="Profile Picture"
                          src={`http://localhost:8070/${editedData?.profilePicture}`}
                          sx={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
                        />
                      </Box>
                    </div>

                    <div className=" flex items-start justify-start gap-3">
                      {/* Name */}
                      <TextField
                        label="Name"
                        name="name"
                        value={editedData?.name}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                        fullWidth
                        className="mb-2"
                      />

                      {/* Address */}
                      <TextField
                        label="Address"
                        name="address"
                        value={editedData?.address}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                        fullWidth
                        className="mb-2"
                      />
                    </div>

                    <TextField
                      label="Years of experience"
                      name="yearsExperience"
                      value={editedData?.yearsExperience}
                      onChange={handleInputChange}
                      fullWidth
                      className="mb-2"
                    />
                    <div className=" flex items-start justify-start gap-3">
                      {/* Age Range */}
                      <TextField
                        label="Age Range Lower Limit"
                        value={editedData?.ageRange?.lowerLimit}
                        name="ageRange"
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                        fullWidth
                        className="mb-2"
                      />
                      <TextField
                        label="Age Range Upper Limit"
                        value={editedData?.ageRange?.upperLimit}
                        name="ageRange"
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                        fullWidth
                        className="mb-2"
                      />
                    </div>

                    {/* Availability */}
                    <TextField
                      label="Availability"
                      name="availability"
                      value={editedData?.availability}
                      onChange={handleInputChange}
                      fullWidth
                      className="mb-2"
                    />

                    {/* Certifications */}
                    <div className="flex items-start justify-center flex-col space-y-2 ">
                      <div className="bg-white p-3 rounded shadow-md  w-full">
                        <div className="mt-1 bg-[#f3f4f6] flex items-center justify-center px-6 pt-5 pb-6 border-2 border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded-md">
                          <div className="space-y-1 text-center ">
                            <label
                              htmlFor="file-upload"
                              className="relative cursor-pointer rounded-md font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 focus-within:outline-none focus-within:border-indigo-300"
                            >
                              <span className="flex items-center justify-center gap-1">
                                <AiOutlineCloudUpload />
                                Upload a file (certificates if any)
                              </span>
                              <input
                                id="file-upload"
                                name="certifications"
                                multiple
                                type="file"
                                accept="image/png,image/jpg,image/jpeg"
                                className="sr-only"
                                onChange={handleCertificateImageChange}
                              />
                            </label>
                            <p className="text-xs text-gray-500">
                              PNG, JPG, JPEG up to 10MB
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="h-4">
                        <span className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-1"></span>
                      </div>
                      <div className="flex items-center justify-start gap-2 w-full flex-wrap">
                        {editedData?.certifications &&
                          editedData?.certifications?.map((img, index) => {
                            return (
                              <>
                                <div>
                                  <Chip
                                    key={index}
                                    label={img}
                                    onDelete={() => removeCertificate(img)}
                                  />
                                  <a
                                    href={`http://localhost:8070/${img}`}
                                    rel="noreferrer"
                                    target="_blank"
                                  >
                                    Veiw
                                  </a>
                                </div>
                              </>
                            );
                          })}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    {/* <TextField
                  label="Certifications"
                  name="certifications"
                  value={editedData.certifications.join(", ")}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  fullWidth
                  className="mb-2"
                /> */}

                    {/* <div className=" flex items-start justify-start gap-3"> */}
                    {/* City */}
                    <TextField
                      label="City"
                      name="city"
                      value={editedData?.city}
                      onChange={handleInputChange}
                      fullWidth
                      className="mb-2"
                    />

                    {/* Preferred Cities */}
                    <div className="mb-2">
                      <TextField
                        label="Preferred cities"
                        name="preferredCities"
                        value={editedData?.preferredCities.join(", ")}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                        fullWidth
                        className="mb-2"
                      />
                      <TextField
                        label="Qualification"
                        name="qualification"
                        value={editedData?.qualification.join(", ")}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                        fullWidth
                        className="mb-2"
                      />
                      {/* <div>
                    {editedData.preferredCities.map((city, index) => (
                      <Chip key={index} label={city} className="mr-1 mb-1" />
                    ))}
                  </div> */}
                    </div>
                    {/* </div> */}
                    <TextField
                      label="Specialisation"
                      name="specialisation"
                      value={editedData?.specialisation.join(", ")}
                      onChange={handleInputChange}
                      fullWidth
                      className="mb-2"
                    />

                    <Button
                      variant="contained"
                      type="submit"
                      className="py-2 px-4 w-full bg-[#1976d2] hover:bg-[#1565c0]"
                    >
                      Save Changes
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                </Paper>
              </Box>
            </form>
          </div>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default UpdateProfileModal;
```

This is my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const connnectDB = require("./config/db");
const cors = require('cors')
const path = require("path")

// dotenv config
dotenv.config();

//mongodb connection
connnectDB();

//rest object
const app = express();

//allow requests from frontend
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['http://localhost:5173']
}))

// middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
// Example configuration
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));


// Handle file upload
// app.use('/api/v1/upload', upload.single('image'), require("./routes/uploadRoutes"))
// routes
app.use('/api/v1/user', require('./routes/userRoutes'))
app.use('/api/v1/admin', require('./routes/adminRoutes'))
app.use('/api/v1/caregiver', require('./routes/caregiverRoutes'))

//port
const port = process.env.PORT || 8070;

//listen port
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(
    `Server running in ${process.env.NODE_MODE} mode on port ${process.env.PORT}`
  );
});
```

This is my route

```
router.patch('/updateCaregiver', upload.single('profilePicture'), upload.array('certifications', 10), authMiddleware, updateCaregiverController)
```

CaregiverController

```
const updateCaregiverController = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await userModel.findOne({ _id: req.body.userId })
        const caregiver = await caregiverModel.findOne({ userId: req.body.userId })
        // const ageRange = JSON.parse(req.body.ageRange)
        let updatedCaregiver
        let updatedUser
        const {
            name,
            address,
            yearsExperience,
            feesPerDay,
            preferredCities,
            description,
            qualification,
            specialisation,
            ageRange,
            availability,
            userId
        } = req.body;

        console.log("REQUEST BODY:", req.body);

        if (caregiver) {
            updatedCaregiver = await caregiverModel.findOneAndUpdate({ userId: userId }, {
                yearsExperience,
                feesPerDay,
                preferredCities,
                description,
                qualification,
                specialisation, ageRange, availability
            }, {
                runValidators: true, new: true
            })
            if (req.files && req.files.certifications) {
                updatedCaregiver.certifications = req.files.certifications.map(file => file.path);
                await updatedCaregiver.save();
            }
        }

        if (user) {
            updatedUser = await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
                { _id: req.body.userId },
                {
                    name,
                    address,
                },
                { runValidators: true, new: true }
            );

            if (req.files && req.files.profilePicture && req.files.profilePicture.length > 0) {
                updatedUser = await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { _id: req.body.userId },
                    {

                        profilePicture: req.files.profilePicture[0].path
                    },
                    { runValidators: true, new: true }
                );

                updatedUser.profilePicture = req.files.profilePicture[0].path;
                await updatedUser.save();
            }

        }

        const data = Object.assign(updatedCaregiver, updatedUser)
        res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            message: "Profile updated successfully",
            data
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            message: "Error while updating nurse details",
            error
        })
    }
}
```

multerConfig.js

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
    },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

module.exports = upload;
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Try using `upload.fields` to combine uploaded files.

Comment: and here `formdata.append(`certifications[${index}]`, certification);` don't need to add index manualy. FormData do this out of box.

Comment: @AlexanderKiselev Thank you so much! It solved my issue. I was stuck at this from almost 2 days.

Comment: @AlexanderKiselev now i am getting unexpected field if i send certifications file. This is my config for upload.fields() : const fieldsConfig = [
    { name: 'profilePicture', maxCount: 1 },
    { name: 'certifications', maxCount: 10 },
];